# New lines inside MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running into an issue where the new lines in my text are not being displayed after retrieval.  Here is how I'm inserting text into the DB:

```
$text = <<<MESSAGE
line1

line2

line3
MESSAGE;

$sql_text = '"'.mysql_real_escape_string($text).'"';

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (text_value) VALUES ($sql_text)";
```

Looking at the data in PHPMyAdmin I see the new lines but when I retrieve it like so:

```
echo str_replace("\r\n", "<br>\n", $text_from_db);
```

It looks like this:

```
line1 line2 line3
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure every line has a `\r\n` at the end and not just a `\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know new lines are `\r\n` ? it could be just `\n`.

Use this statement to check,

```
echo nl2br($text_from_db);
```

Answer (score 0):

The line breaks could be `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`. [nl2br()](http://php.net/nl2br) handles all these cases:

```
echo nl2br($text_from_db);
```